# php beginner-basic php variable in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

PHP variable not working in sql query..

Am just a begginer in php. pls tell where am going wrong.thanks in advances.

```
$sql = 'SELECT email_id FROM dealer WHERE dealerid="'mysql_real_escape_string($id).'"';

$rt  = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rt);

if($row) {
  echo "<h1>Number:</h1>" . $row[0];
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rt)) {
    var_dump($row);
  }
}
```

Comment: why you are fetching two times?

Comment: I've improved the readability of your code a little. As a beginner this may not be very high on your list; but properly aligned and indented code will save you time and often tell you the mistakes right away.

Comment: thanks u everyone for ur answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error on line 1, you need a "`.`" between `'`and mysql

```
$sql = 'SELECT email_id FROM dealer WHERE dealerid="' . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . '"';
```

Answer (score 4):

you forgot to properly concatenation of string it should be like

```
$sql = 'SELECT email_id FROM dealer WHERE dealerid="' . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . '"';
```

[String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

your code will probably give you

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line bla
```

This is a syntax error, meaning that there is something in your code stopping it from being parsed correctly and therefore run.

**What you should do** is check carefully at the lines around where the error is for any simple mistakes

so make sure you enable at least `E_PARSE` in your `php.ini`. Parse errors should not exist in production scripts.

i always recommended to while coding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

[error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

---

**Note**

1. Its not true that we are using `mysql_real_escape_string()`  and we are completly safe form sql injection [cheak this answer by @ircmaxell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/1723893)
2. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$sql = "SELECT email_id FROM dealer WHERE dealerid='$escaped'";
```